# Zoom out on a small view with ScaleGestureDetector

Tags: android, android-view, pinchzoom

I have a custom view with a ScaleGestureDetector, on which I want to use pinch to zoom action. 
It works ok when the view is rather large, but when it is small only zomm in works properly (I place two fingers on the view and move them in different directions), when I try to zoom out (place two fingers on the view and move the together) nothing happens. Here is the screenshot:
[image]

The problem appears in the small views that are in the center.
In the top and bottom larger views zomm in and zoom out work properly.

the code is:

```
private class MyScaleGestureListener implements OnScaleGestureListener
{
    public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector)
    {
        scaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();
        if (scaleFactor < 1)
            scaleFactor = 1;

        int newScrollX = (int)((getScrollX() + detector.getFocusX()) * detector.getScaleFactor() - detector.getFocusX());
        int newScrollY = (int)((getScrollY() + detector.getFocusY()) * detector.getScaleFactor() - detector.getFocusY());
        scrollTo(newScrollX, newScrollY);

        invalidate();

        return true;
    }

    public boolean onScaleBegin(ScaleGestureDetector detector)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void onScaleEnd(ScaleGestureDetector detector)
    {
    }
}
```

How to make zoom out work on small views?

Answer (score 0):

There is a mechanizm of recognizing sloppy gestures in android. To be able to zoom out on a small view you should make your own ScaleGestureDetector with all code responsible for sloppy gestures removed. You can take original code from here https://code.google.com/p/android-vnc-viewer/source/browse/branches/antlersoft/androidVNC/src/com/antlersoft/android/bc/ScaleGestureDetector.java?r=164.